# What is the environment variable XDG_VTNR?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, tty

Almost every page I've found is about to automatically start Xorg after login wihout explianation, take `~/.bash_profile` for example:

```
if [[ ! $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]]; then
  exec xinit
fi
```

I suppose `$XDG_VTNR` could be a variable for obtaining the current TTY number, however, there is already a command called `tty`, which can meet the same purpose.

My questions:

1. What is `$XDG_VTNR`? Where and when is it being set?
2. Where can I find the official documentation about this variable?
3. `tty` is a built-in command while `$XDG_VTNR` is provided by Xorg, why people choose to use `$XDG_VTNR` instead of built-in `tty`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is `$XDG_VTNR`? Where and when is it being set?

It's set by the `pam_systemd` PAM module, and is only set on machines which are using systemd, which means that you should **not** rely on it in your scripts, unless you want to make them depend on systemd.

On systems which are using systemd, `$XDG_VTNR` will be set both in graphical (by `lightdm`, `gdm`, etc) and in text-mode sessions (by `/bin/login`).

> Where can I find the official documentation about this variable?

In the [`pam_systemd(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_systemd.8.html) manpage.

> `tty` is a built-in command while `$XDG_VTNR` is provided by Xorg, why people choose to use `$XDG_VTNR` instead of built-in `tty`?

1) `tty` is a standalone program, not a built-in, and `$XDG_VTNR` is not provided by Xorg.

2) Because they're completely different things. As clearly stated in its manpage, `tty(1)` will tell you the name of the terminal connected to its standard input, not the name of the virtual terminal your GUI session or such may be running on[1]. Consider this:

```
$ script -q /dev/null
$ tty
/dev/pts/5
$ script -q /dev/null
$ tty
/dev/pts/6
$ tty </dev/zero
not a tty
```

[1] for which `XDG_VTNR` isn't a reliable indicator either.

Comment: This is misleading, XDG_VTRN is available in at least GhostBSD, which obviously does not have systemd. I believe the quote you gave is correct however, this is an Xorg item, not a systemd related item. I don't know what sets it, it may vary.

Comment: I don't know what GhostBSD is, but I know that some BSDs have a systemd shim, in order to fool the GNOME stuff which has come to depend on systemd. On linux, `XDG_VTNR` is set by `pam_systemd`, as described in the linked manpage.

Answer (score -1):

`XDG_VTNR` is a somewhat poorly documented environmental variable. Systemd uses/sets it. See `systemd.exec`and `pam_systemd` man pages. Some display managers also use/set it. Some X11 startup scripts use/set it.

From `systemd/pam_systemd.c`:

```
if (vtnr > 0) {
            char buf[DECIMAL_STR_MAX(vtnr)];
            sprintf(buf, "%u", vtnr);

            r = update_environment(handle, "XDG_VTNR", buf);
            if (r != PAM_SUCCESS)
                    return r;
}
```

You can start an X11 session within a virtual terminal (VT), not just in your console. The `XDG_VTNR` variable specifies the VT number.

The additional `DISPLAY` test is necessary since the code snippet may be executed on both graphical and non-graphical logins. Since `XDG_VTNR` will be set to the same value in the shells started within the X11 session (e.g. terminals), it is necessary to prevent them from trying to start X11.

The `exec` command replaces the login shell with the X11 session. This means that when the X11 session terminates, you will be logged out.