# How to know on which virtual console X11 is running?

Tags: x11, virtual-consoles

I want to know on which virtual console the X11 is runnning. Of course, I can know it by invoking the ps command and watching the process tree. Or, I can know it by pressing ctrl+alt+F1, ctrl+alt+F2, ... But it is nice if there is an easier way.

When the system is in CUI mode, I can know it by the tty command. But under X11, the tty command tells me such as /dev/pts/0 and it doesn't seem to be a clue to the virtual console. Is there is any connection between tty* and pst/*?

In my environment, X11 is usually running on tty1. But in some rare case, it runs on another console. If I can know the console easily, it helps me a lot.

P.S.

Recently I knew the following fact:

On machies using systemd, the environment variable $XDG_VTNR is set to the number of the virtual console.

[What is the environment variable XDG_VTNR?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521037/what-is-the-environment-variable-xdg-vtnr)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `fgconsole` command. In Debian it's included in the package kbd.

For example:

```
$ fgconsole
7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always run `grep "using VT number " /var/log/Xorg.0.log`. I'll leave it to you on how to extract the number.